# How to store continuous user input in an array?

Tags: c#

For example:

```
  user input: 12345
```

then each integer will be placed inside an array.

```
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Comment: What type of application?

Answer (score 1):

You can try some variation on the following

```
//get user input as a string and convert to integer array


int[] num = "12345".Select(a => Int32.Parse(a.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
string str1 = "123456";
    int[] arr = new int[str1.Length];
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= str1.Length - 1; ctr++)
    {
        arr[ctr] = Convert.ToInt16(str1[ctr].ToString());
    }
```

Demo result:

[image]

Take a look at Page load event code only.... :p Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
String input="123456";
int [] intArray=new int[input.Length];
int count=0;
foreach(var ch in input)
{
intArray[count]=Convert.ToInt32(ch.ToString());
count++;
}
```